# Means of powers of the zeta function

Tags: reference-request, analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta

It is well known that [the Lindel\"of Hypothesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lindel%C3%B6f_hypothesis) is equivalent to the statement that $$\frac 1T\int_0^T|\zeta(1/2=it)|^{2k} =O(T^\epsilon)$$ for all positive integers $k$ and all positive real $\epsilon$, and these fact are known for $k=1, 2$. May  I ask you for references to the proofs.

Comment: In papers and chapters (Titchmarsh and others) about the  [Dirichlet divisor problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_summatory_function#Dirichlet's_divisor_problem)

Comment: Do you mean the equivalence? I am interested in the proofs of the estimate for $k=1, 2$.

Comment: https://zulfahmed.files.wordpress.com/2018/08/titchmarsh-and-d-r-heath-brown-the-theory-of-the-riemann-zeta-function.pdf p.74-75

Comment: Thanks! Just a remark: this is the chapter of Titchmarsh titled 'Mean value theorems'. (You have answered my question, I am ready to accept.)